# Can't find keys for keyboard module

Tags: python, keyboard

I've been looking all over for the keys documentation on the `keyboard` module. But i can't seem to find it. Is it anywhere and I just haven't been looking in the right places...? I don't really know but i found it weird since it is a fairly used module. So I'd appreciate it if someone could help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is under [keyboard API](http://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#api) - if you read the documentation and sources of send(..) you can follow:

[send()](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/e277e3f2baf53ee1d7901cbb562f443f8f861b90/keyboard/__init__.py#L361) ->  [parse_hotkey(hotkey)](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/e277e3f2baf53ee1d7901cbb562f443f8f861b90/keyboard/__init__.py#L328) -> [key_to_scan_codes(key, error_if_missing=True)](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/e277e3f2baf53ee1d7901cbb562f443f8f861b90/keyboard/__init__.py#L298) -> [normalize_name(key)](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/e277e3f2baf53ee1d7901cbb562f443f8f861b90/keyboard/_canonical_names.py#L1233) ->  [canonical_names.get(name, name)](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/e277e3f2baf53ee1d7901cbb562f443f8f861b90/keyboard/_canonical_names.py#L12)

which lists all canonical names.

But you never need that - you can simply put the letter you want to send as string in the `send()` method so as long as you can type it you do not need any documentation.

The modifiers are documented [here](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.all_modifiers).